# Attachinterrupt frequency arduino

Tags: arduino

I have this project where i need to build a synthethiser , our only problem is getting the frequency back to arduino. I don't have a picture of it but heres a simulation on proteus.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHvdR.png)

I tried to calculate the period for 500ms and then divide it by each rising that occured but i only get 0 for my frequency

```
volatile int prev_time = 0;
volatile int now_time = 0;
volatile int periode1 = 0;
volatile int periode = 0;
volatile int frequence = 0;
volatile int compteur=0;
unsigned long tempsactuel=millis();


int donnee = 2;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(donnee, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(donnee), rising, RISING);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(tempsactuel>500)
  {
    periode=periode/compteur;
   frequence=1/periode;
   compteur=0;
   periode=0;
   tempsactuel=0;
  }
  
  Serial.println(periode);
 Serial.println(frequence);
  
}

void rising()
{
  now_time = micros();
  periode1 = now_time - prev_time;
  prev_time = now_time;
  periode=periode1+periode;
 compteur++;
}
```

(Btw I can't use timer1 since i'm already using it for something else)

```css
volatile int prev_time = 0;
volatile int now_time = 0;
volatile int periode1 = 0;
volatile int periode = 0;
float frequence = 0;
volatile int compteur=0;
unsigned long tempsactuel=millis();
unsigned long tempsprecedent=0;

int donnee = 2;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(donnee, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(donnee), rising, RISING);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(tempsactuel-tempsprecedent>500)
  {
    periode=periode/compteur;
   frequence=1/(float)periode;
   compteur=0;
   periode=0;
   tempsprecendent=tempsactuel;
  }
  
 Serial.println(periode);
 Serial.println(frequence);
  
}

void rising()
{
  now_time = micros();
  periode1 = now_time - prev_time;
  prev_time = now_time;
  periode=periode1+periode;
 compteur++;
}
```

Comment: how should `tempsactuel` get to 500?

Comment: As you declare `periode` and `frequence` as integers, dividing stuff into them might not work well.

Comment: Ok , thank you Juraj and droopsnoot , i don't actually have my project on myself right now but do you think it would work like that ?